# Running javascript inside rest api

Tags: php, websocket, asterisk

I'm working on asterisk.
I managed to call an external api using dialplan.
Now I want to run a javascript inside that api function, because I need to notify a browser that someone is calling. What I'm thinking is that I can do that using node.js. I don't want to use ajax polling cause it is bad.

The following are the process when someone is calling

Call -> Trigger dialplan -> Call external api via AGI method -> run javascript websocket event inside api -> notify browser.

Is that possible? or there is much better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes" - but it also depends on the API you want to use, and what you're attempting to accomplish.

Asterisk has three "main" APIs: AMI, AGI, and ARI. AMI and AGI have existed for a long time; ARI - the Asterisk REST Interface - is relatively new. To quote from the [Asterisk wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573):

> Not long into the project, two application programming interfaces
>   (APIs) were added to Asterisk: the Asterisk Gateway Interface (AGI)
>   and the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI). These interfaces have
>   distinct purposes:
>
> 1. AGI is analogous to CGI in Apache. AGI provides an interface between the Asterisk dialplan and an external program that wants to
>      manipulate a channel in the dialplan. In general, the interface is
>      synchronous - actions taken on a channel from an AGI block and do not
>      return until the action is completed.
> 2. AMI provides a mechanism to control where channels execute in the dialplan. Unlike AGI, AMI is an asynchronous, event driven interface.
>      For the most part, AMI does not provide mechanisms to control channel
>      execution - rather, it provides information about the state of the
>      channels and controls about where the channels are executing

Unlike AMI and AGI, ARI is all about letting you write your own dialplan applications. If you're interested in it, I highly suggest you check out the wiki page linked above.

The API you choose should be based on what you're looking to accomplish. Since you're looking to do a call pop, you really could do that either AMI (by listening for some event trigger) or through ARI (by having the channel enter the [Stasis](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Stasis) dialplan application, executing a custom node.js ARI application).

There are node.js libraries for both APIs:

**AMI**

- [node-asterisk-ami](https://github.com/holidayextras/node-asterisk-ami)
- [Nami](https://github.com/marcelog/Nami)
- [yana](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yana)

**ARI**

- [node-ari-client](https://github.com/asterisk/node-ari-client)

Answer (score 0):

You said that "want to notify a browser that someone is calling", so I think the **Web Socket** is the solution you are looking for.

> WebSocket is defined as a two-way communication between the servers and the clients, which mean both the parties, communicate and exchange data at the same time.

The [Asterisk 17 Events REST API](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+17+Events+REST+API) describes that WebSocket connection used for events,
here is an [example](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+Started+with+ARI#GettingStartedwithARI-HelloWorld!) to generate a WebSocket connection in CLI Asterisk.

### Here is my situation tested:

[image]

The http server node has **2 roles**:

1. be a **WebSocket client**, it gets messages from the server Asterisk via ARI (Aterisk Rest Interface).
2. be a **http server that attaches socket.io**, it notifies some informations to all socket.io clients

---

### 1. Create a user in /etc/asterisk/ari.conf

Here I defined a user 'toto' with password 'pass1'

[image]

### 2. app.js

npm install websocket socket.io

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// Loading the index.html file displayed to the client (browser)
var httpserver = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });   
});


// create a ws connection to the server asterisk
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws_client = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.141.235:8088/ari/events?api_key=toto:pass1&app=hello&subscribeAll=true');


// ws_client listens to the event 'error' for getting errors 
// when the server asterisk has some socket connection problems
ws_client.on('error',function error(error){ 
    console.log(error);
})

// create an instance socket.io attached to http server
var io_httpserver = require('socket.io')(httpserver);


//listens all clients which connect to the socket 'mysocket', 
//in this case we have only one client (sokcet.io_client_1) in index.html
io_httpserver.sockets.on('connection', function (mysocket) {
    // ws_client listens to the event 'message' for getting data of the server asterisk
    ws_client.on('message',function show(data){
        //send data to all clients which listen to the custom event 'titi' 
        mysocket.emit('titi',data); 
    })
  });

httpserver.listen(8080);
```

### 3. index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Socket.io</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Real time application</h1>
        <table id="one" class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">date</th>
                  <th scope="col">endpoints</th>
                  <th scope="col">states</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
        </table>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
         var tab = document.getElementById('one');
         var sokcet_io_client_1 = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
            sokcet_io_client_1.on('titi', function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                if(obj.type=="DeviceStateChanged"){
                    var date = obj.timestamp.split('.')[0].replace("T", "  ");
                    tab.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<td>'+date+'</td><td>'+obj.device_state.name+'</td><td>'+obj.device_state.state+'</td>');
                }
                })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally load app.js :

```
node app.js
```

Result:
[image]